# How to check if a UDP packet is sent at transmitter

Tags: c++, qt, network-programming, udp

I am trying to send a packet using UDP. I know that if the channel is not free the packet will not be sent. I am using QT's `udpSocket->writeDatagram` to send a UDP packet. I am doing it in a loop, I want to make sure I do not send another packet before the previous packet has been sent. Is there a flag, or any other way that I can check and make sure the packet is sent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qudpsocket.html#writeDatagram) say:

> Sends the datagram at *data* of size *size* to the host address *address* at
>   port *port*. Returns the number of bytes sent on success; otherwise
>   returns -1.

So if it returns something other than `-1` you can consider it "sent". However, if what you really want to know is whether it made it to the other side, you'll want to hear from the peer.

Comment: Thanks that is correct I overlooked this explanation in the QT documentation.

Answer (score 5):

UDP is an unreliable protocol by design. It does not guarantee that packets don't get lost, and when they get lost, the sender is not informed about that. So you can never know if a UDP packet was received successfully by the other side.

Unless, of course, your application level protocol sends a certain response. But the response can get lost just as easily, so no response is no definite proof that the packet wasn't received.

Answer (score 3):

Typically in order to send UDP packets as fast as possible (but no faster), you'll want to put the socket into non-blocking mode, then send packets in a loop until send()/sendto() returns -1/EAGAIN (aka EWOULDBLOCK).  When that result-code is returned, break out of your send-loop loop and wait for the socket to become writable again.  Under Qt, you can set up a QSocketNotifier object (once, right after you set up your socket) and it will emit an activated(int) signal whenever your socket has space for more outgoing data.  When you receive that signal, you can send some more packets.

Comment: Yes, that strategy might precisely saturate the sender's network interface. But it also might overwhelm the receiver's interface or any intermediate network.

Comment: Thanks of the answer, this is useful.